# Pegar relação inversa com Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-eloquent

Estou criando um sistema de fórum que é dividido por seções. Cada seção contém categorias, cada categoria contém tópicos. Ex:

```
Administração _
               |_Regras da do fórum
               |_Sugestões e críticas

Aeromodelismo _
               |_Elétricos _
               |_Glow       |-Tópico 1
                            |-Tópico 2
                            |-Tópico N
```

Ao entrar no fórum eu preciso pegar os últimos tópicos respondidos onde (*where*) o id da seção = X.

Em resumo eu preciso pegar os últimos tópicos respondidos dentro de uma seção específica, mas há que considerar que na tabela 'tópicos' a chave estrangeira faz referencia à categoria, e na tabela 'categorias' a chave estrangeira faz referência à seção, ou seja, os tópicos são 'netos' das seções.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bem, eu implementaria dessa forma:

Unificaria as Categorias e sessões em uma única tabela, adicionando uma coluna "id_pai", referenciando a própria tabela sessões e permitindo nulos. Assim as sessões seriam as Categorias com `id_pai` nulo.

Para retornar os tópicos de uma sessão específica, basta um `DB::table('sessoes')->where('id_pai', 4)->get()->toArray();` para ter um array com o id de todas as categorias e por fim utilizar esse array em uma query com `whereIn`

**Exemplo:**

```
$categorias = DB::table('sessoes')->where('id_pai', 4)->get()->toArray();
$topicos = DB::table('topicos ')
                    ->whereIn('id',$categorias)->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Se o problema é apenas ordenar...

```
Model::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->get();
```

Mais informações http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#query-scopes

Comment: O problema não é ordenar. Eu preciso pegar os tópicos que são 'netos' de uma sessão, mas sem ter que fazer aquele monte de query pra pegar as categorias que são filhas da sessão e depois pegar os tópicos que são filhos das categorias.

Comment: Eu achei que não fosse, mas então pega e edita tua pergunta com o código que tu ta usando.

Comment: Esse é o problema, não consigo nem pensar em como vou fazer isso. Não tenho código ainda.